# Как убить процессы, которые старше получаса, скажем, в Debian?

Tags: debian

Использую headless chrome вместе с Puppeteer в cron, и иногда это все виснет и процессы остаются в памяти. Можно ли их как-то прибить? Для убивания всех таких процессов использую

```
kill $(ps aux | grep 'node_modules' | awk '{print $2}')
```

А можно ли как-то из ps aux выудить время старта процесса, и прибивать только процессы старше определенного времен, например, запущенные более чем полчаса назад?
Также, из-за забивания памяти такими процессами, перестает работать cron. Можно ли с этим что-то сделать?
Спасибо.

Comment: Можно вывести время, которое процесс отработал `ps -eo "%p %t"` выведет в заголовке -- ` PID     ELAPSED`, в колонке со временем hh:mm:ss (hh (часы) может отсутствовать)

Comment: Проверьте вывод, возможно поможет `ps -Ao "%p;%t" | grep -P -v '(00){0,1}[0-2][0-9]:[0-9]{2}$'`

Answer (score 3):

Запускайте такие процессы через `timeout`

```
timeout 15m long_command
```

Если команда `long_command` не завершится за указанные 15 минут - то утилита `timeout` пошлёт ей сигнал завершения процесса `TERM`.

Comment: Я запускаю процессы так:
    node /home/path/my.js blablabla >/dev/null 2>&1
а уже node запускает хром и puppeteer, и получаются такие процессы:
    /node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-609904/chrome-linux/chrome --disable-background-networking ...

Comment: @РоманКистин  А вы всё-ж попробуйте, реализовать то что вам посоветовали. Какая реакция?

Comment: вот там где запускаются процессы иногда уходящие в себя - из через timeout и запускайте. Можно через подмену приоритета PATH переадресовать на другой скрипт, например. Впрочем, я предполагал что кто-нибудь напишет способ для именно того о чём вы спрашивали, а мой ответ будет описанием альтернативного способа.